# Difference in usage between "se rabaisser" and "s’abaisser" in a figurative sense

Tags: sens, usage

> Je ne vais pas ***me rabaisser à ce point*** !
>
> Je ne vais pas ***m’abaisser à polémiquer*** sur ça !

Is it just me, or does "s’abaisser" only (or mostly) take "à + infinitive" while "se rabaisser" comes with "à + noun", as shown in the examples above? Or can you just switch the two around?

> Je ne vais pas ***m'abaisser à ce point*** !
>
> Je ne vais pas ***me rabaisser à polémiquer*** sur ça !

And what about the nuances of meaning between these two similar expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S' « abaisser » a un sens physique et signifie « baisser vers qqchose ». J'abaisse la selle de mon vélo à ma hauteur.

Il me semble que « rabaisser » a plus un sens moral. « Je ne vais pas me rabaisser à polémiquer sur ça » veut dire « Je ne vais pas perdre de temps à polémiquer sur ça, cela n'en vaut pas la peine/je vaux mieux que ça. »

Answer (score 0):

Both forms means here to lower our own level/role/rank in order to do something, often in an humiliating way.

Theoretically, *rabaisser* is "to lower something that is too high or that has been previously raised" while *abaisser* is simply "to lower something" but I doubt that really makes a difference here. Maybe the former is a little stronger.

*S'abaisser à* is probably preferred in literature/formal French but otherwise, both are interchangeable so your four sentences are idiomatic